# I do Have a .pem file from aws ec2 Instance. But the instance has no key name attached to it.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I Created an EC2 instance in aws. 
I saved the .pem file and I have it.
But in the instance dashboard the key name field has no value assigned to it. 
When I try to connect using putty it says "server refused our key".
But the Key I'm loading with putty is what I downloaded while I created the instance.Please help me out with this. TIA.

Comment: It sounds like you launched the EC2 instance without a keypair so you haven't been able to access it at all, so haven't made any changes to it. Why don't you just terminate it and launch a new one with a keypair? Or in the EC2 console, right click | Launch more like this, and then choose the desired keypair.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

1.)  As others have said, you launched instance without a key.  In that case, you won't be able to login.  Terminate the instance, and launch a new one.  Be sure to specify a key.

2.)  You have a key, but `PuTTY` won't take it.  Default format for key downloaded from AWS is `.pem`, but `PuTTY` needs `.ppk` format.  Use `PuTTYgen` to convert from `.pem` to `.ppk`.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you created the key, but didn't actually assign the key to the instance. You will probably have to delete the instance and recreate it, paying attention to assign the key to the new instance when you are creating it.